# Counting values by month with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to count the number of values per month in the sample.purpose.label column in this water quality dataset (All of England, 2019, both compliance and monitoring) https://environment.data.gov.uk/water-quality/view/download/new

For example, I want to know how many times the COMPLIANCE FORMAL (PERMIT) was issued in January, and so on.

I can't seem to work out the code to do it by month. I'm sure it's a pretty easy solution but have been on it for days without any luck. I made a pandas dataframe and then a separate month column already. This is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv (r"C:\Users\Downloads\water_testing\2019.csv")

df['sample.sampleDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sample.sampleDateTime'])

df.drop(['sample.samplingPoint','sample.samplingPoint.notation','sample.samplingPoint.label', 'determinand.label', 'determinand.definition', 'determinand.notation', 'resultQualifier.notation', 'result', 'codedResultInterpretation.interpretation', 'determinand.unit.label', 'sample.sampledMaterialType.label', 'sample.isComplianceSample', 'sample.samplingPoint.easting', 'sample.samplingPoint.northing'],inplace=True,axis=1)

df.rename(columns = {'sample.sampleDateTime':'time'}, inplace = True)

df['time'].dt.month_name()
```

Any guidance would be very greatly appreciated, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to group by month, [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to count all occurrences of each item in `sample.purpose.label`, and [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to reshape

```
df = pd.read_csv('2019.csv')
df['sample.sampleDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sample.sampleDateTime'])
df.set_index('sample.sampleDateTime').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))['sample.purpose.label'].value_counts().unstack(level=1)
```

output:

```
sample.purpose.label   COMPLIANCE AUDIT (PERMIT)  COMPLIANCE FORMAL (PERMIT)  ENVIRONMENTAL MONITORING STATUTORY (EU DIRECTIVES)  IPPC/IPC MONITORING (AGENCY AUDIT - PERMIT)  IPPC/IPC MONITORING (AGENCY INVESTIGATION)  IPPC/IPC MONITORING (FORMAL SAMPLE)  MONITORING  (NATIONAL AGENCY POLICY)  MONITORING  (UK GOVT POLICY - NOT GQA OR RE)  PLANNED FORMAL NON-STATUTORY (PERMIT/ENV MON)  PLANNED INVESTIGATION (LOCAL MONITORING)  PLANNED INVESTIGATION (NATIONAL AGENCY POLICY)  STATUTORY FAILURES (FOLLOW UPS AT DESIGNATED POINTS)  STATUTORY FAILURES (FOLLOW UPS AT NON-DESIGNATED POINTS)  UNPLANNED REACTIVE MONITORING (POLLUTION INCIDENTS)  UNPLANNED REACTIVE MONITORING FORMAL (POLLUTION INCIDENTS)  WASTE MONITORING (AGENCY AUDIT - PERMIT)  WASTE MONITORING (AGENCY INVESTIGATION)  WASTE MONITORING (FORMAL SAMPLE)  WATER QUALITY OPERATOR SELF MONITORING COMPLIANCE DATA  WATER QUALITY UWWTD MONITORING DATA
sample.sampleDateTime                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
2019-01-31                                5219.0                        44.0                                             47360.0                                          NaN                                       887.0                                  NaN                                2498.0                                       10624.0                                            NaN                                    8534.0                                           823.0                                                2599.0                                                    7556.0                                               2787.0                                                      1491.0                                       NaN                                     12.0                               NaN                                                 11800.0                               8359.0
2019-02-28                                3971.0                        22.0                                             53000.0                                         38.0                                       536.0                                  NaN                                2537.0                                       10053.0                                            NaN                                   10688.0                                           702.0                                                3023.0                                                    8295.0                                               2930.0                                                      1151.0                                       NaN                                    534.0                             624.0                                                 11781.0                               5443.0
2019-03-31                                3838.0                        52.0                                             42524.0                                         31.0                                       689.0                                 18.0                                5548.0                                        9273.0                                            9.0                                    9630.0                                           786.0                                                2084.0                                                    5995.0                                               2792.0                                                       734.0                                       NaN                                    415.0                             443.0                                                 12275.0                               5672.0
2019-04-30                                3865.0                        34.0                                             73070.0                                         24.0                                        55.0                                  NaN                                3450.0                                        6665.0                                            NaN                                    8202.0                                          7073.0                                                1261.0                                                    4827.0                                               2225.0                                                      1144.0                                       NaN                                   2175.0                               NaN                                                 12168.0                               5409.0
2019-05-31                                3695.0                        44.0                                             96911.0                                         27.0                                        58.0                                  NaN                                3053.0                                        7006.0                                            NaN                                    7663.0                                          9299.0                                                1356.0                                                    4665.0                                               2293.0                                                      1296.0                                       NaN                                    194.0                             188.0                                                 11982.0                               5934.0
2019-06-30                                3029.0                        36.0                                             83428.0                                         13.0                                         8.0                                  NaN                                5284.0                                        5362.0                                           24.0                                   10340.0                                          9402.0                                                2344.0                                                    5318.0                                               2299.0                                                      1217.0                                       NaN                                    278.0                              14.0                                                 12109.0                               5643.0
2019-07-31                                4385.0                        62.0                                            100697.0                                         24.0                                         NaN                                  NaN                                6574.0                                       11328.0                                            NaN                                    7820.0                                         10448.0                                                1551.0                                                    4539.0                                               3536.0                                                      1647.0                                       NaN                                   1278.0                             535.0                                                 13413.0                               5858.0
2019-08-31                                3196.0                        38.0                                             85826.0                                         38.0                                        15.0                                  NaN                                4018.0                                        6266.0                                            NaN                                    9474.0                                         10375.0                                                2253.0                                                    5989.0                                               2304.0                                                      1023.0                                     240.0                                     95.0                             186.0                                                 12303.0                               5514.0
2019-09-30                                3519.0                         8.0                                             88239.0                                         17.0                                       244.0                                  NaN                                7008.0                                        7007.0                                            NaN                                    8234.0                                         10809.0                                                1702.0                                                    4151.0                                               1774.0                                                      1345.0                                       NaN                                      NaN                            2422.0                                                 12895.0                               5617.0
2019-10-31                                4569.0                        28.0                                             91347.0                                         24.0                                         NaN                                  NaN                                7416.0                                        7214.0                                            NaN                                   16760.0                                         12467.0                                                1152.0                                                    3567.0                                               1690.0                                                      1078.0                                     120.0                                    595.0                             373.0                                                 13023.0                               5975.0
2019-11-30                                4290.0                         8.0                                             76318.0                                         38.0                                         NaN                                 30.0                                8172.0                                        6024.0                                            NaN                                    5315.0                                         11514.0                                                  31.0                                                    1352.0                                               1540.0                                                      1036.0                                       NaN                                   1255.0                             360.0                                                 13196.0                               6042.0
2019-12-31                                3356.0                        17.0                                             71900.0                                         24.0                                        14.0                                  NaN                                5331.0                                        6138.0                                            NaN                                    6520.0                                         10673.0                                                 849.0                                                    1930.0                                               1725.0                                                      1010.0                                       NaN                                   2894.0                             895.0                                                  9425.0                               4329.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df["Month"] = df["time"].dt.month
>>> df.groupby(["Month", "sample.purpose.label"]).count().unstack()
                                           @id  ...                                time
sample.purpose.label COMPLIANCE AUDIT (PERMIT)  ... WATER QUALITY UWWTD MONITORING DATA
Month                                           ...                                    
1                                       5219.0  ...                              8359.0
2                                       3971.0  ...                              5443.0
3                                       3838.0  ...                              5672.0
4                                       3865.0  ...                              5409.0
5                                       3695.0  ...                              5934.0
6                                       3029.0  ...                              5643.0
7                                       4385.0  ...                              5858.0
8                                       3196.0  ...                              5514.0
9                                       3519.0  ...                              5617.0
10                                      4569.0  ...                              5975.0
11                                      4290.0  ...                              6042.0
12                                      3356.0  ...                              4329.0

[12 rows x 40 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you, that has returned the total number of licenses given each month, whereas I am looking for the number of each type of license given in a month. The sample.purpose.label column contains a range of different license types. Is there a bit of code I can add to this?